# RecyclerView goes out of bounds for the size of toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I create new android project, pick main activity from gallery to be Tabbed activity, and add RecyclerView to be the main fragment content in layout file instead of already provided TextView from template. I add the LinearLayoutManager to RecyclerView. Simple as that.

What happens after I start this simple demo is that RecyclerView goes out of the screen bounds no matter of the size set to match_parent. It goes out of bounds for the size of toolbar and my screen gets scrollable, which is the behavior I don't want.

If I put ListView instead of RecyclerView or put RecyclerView without LayoutManager, or remove the toolbar, everything gets normal (no screen scrolling).

Here is the the content of the fragment_main.xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
tools:context="test.com.myapplication.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
```

Here is piece of Fragment code that inflates view:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
```

Here is the gif of activity behavior:
[Screen that scrolls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ8K4.gif)

What should I do so that RecyclerView fits the bounds and not make my activity scrollable? Like I said, it works when: change RecyclerView to ListView, or remove toolbar, but I  need to know how to solve this with RecyclerView and toolbar.